# Removing contract to release RAM - the smallest contract possible

Tags: smart-contract, ram

Check our github
https://github.com/irespo/irespo/tree/master/irespo/iresporemove
I did a sample contract with one empty action, but it is still 30 KB.
I tried a contract without action, but did not work.
Anyone has ideas how to optimize it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 19th September:** As of [v1.3.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.3.0), it is now possible to delete the smart contract from an account using the `--clear` flag (`$ cleos set contract <account> --clear`)

---

To make a small contract, I suggest not using `cpp` or `eosiocpp`/`eosio-cpp` at all. The smallest contract I managed to upload on chain takes 0.392 KiB and it's written in webassembly:

**contract.wast**

```
(module
 (export "apply" (func $apply))
 (func $apply (param $0 i64) (param $1 i64) (param $2 i64))
)
```

**contract.abi**

```
{
  "____comment": "",
  "version": "eosio::abi/1.0",
  "types": [],
  "structs": [],
  "actions": [],
  "tables": [],
  "ricardian_clauses": [],
  "error_messages": [],
  "abi_extensions": []
}
```

Use `wat2wasm` binary from [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) to convert the `wast` file into a `wasm` binary that will take up 38 bytes. When you upload it on the chain, 38 bytes * 10 = 0.38 KB which is a decrease of almost 99% in size and costs from 30KB.

Comment: Can you recommend any good sources to learn web assembly?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett i'm probably not the best person to answer this as i'm still in the process of learning wasm myself, but i just used [this](https://github.com/mbasso/awesome-wasm/blob/master/README.md) page for finding resources